# Правильное написание слова

Tags: правописание

Как правильно пишется слово: "...вглядываясь в коротко()стриже(н)ную макушку."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Правильно: вглядываясь в коротко стриже***нн***ую макушку, но: стриженые волосы.  Причастия **не** на -ованный (-ёванный, -еванный) глаголов несовершенного вида (они образуются Только от бесприставочных глаголов) и соотносительные с ними прилагательные пишутся по-разному: причастия с нн, прилагательные — с одним н. Причастия, как правило,  имеют при себе зависимые слова.  Ср.: ране***н***ый солдат, но: ране***нн***ый в голову солдат.

Comment: См. "короткостриженые волосы": https://www.google.ru/search?q=%22%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5+%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8B%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=z9UOVePnDKLpywOjiILoAQ#q=%22%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5+%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8B%22&newwindow=1&nfpr=1&tbm=bks&start=10

Answer (score 0):

Можно и *"в короткостриженую"*, и *"в коротко стриженную".* См.:

http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%EA%EE%F0%EE%F2%EA%EE%F1%F2%F0%E8%E6%E5%ED%FB%E9&all=x

http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%EA%EE%F0%EE%F2%EA%EE+%F1%F2%F0%E8%E6%E5%ED%ED%FB%E9

Я бы выбрал второй вариант -- ***"в коротко стриженную"*** (так чаще пишут).

См. https://www.google.ru/search?q=%22%D0%B2+%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=SMQOVcmjOarmywPHqYEQ#q=%22%D0%B2+%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BE+%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E%22&newwindow=1&tb